# About Spinners and button interface

Tags: java, android

how do I combine the
slected item of 3 spinners i have created and link it to a button??
here is my code...

```
    package com.example.nikhiljoshi.time_table;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        char branch1;
    Spinner spbranch,spsem,spdiv;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter1;
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>adapter2;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button Submit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        spbranch = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spsem = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        spdiv = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);

        adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.branch,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spbranch.setAdapter(adapter);
        spbranch.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                int i;

               // branch1=spbranch.getItemAtPosition(i).toString();

            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.sem,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spsem.setAdapter(adapter1);

        adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.division,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spdiv.setAdapter(adapter2);



        Submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


               // Toast.makeText(view, "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                 //       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             //  Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), nik.class);
             // startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }
        });


        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}



layout...

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Branch"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="105dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="27dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="34dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/button" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Sem"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Division"
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/spinner2" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Submit"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="48dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enter the details"
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

when i press the submit button, the following things should happen
for eg
if(branch=='cs'&& sem=='5' && div=='A')
then new activity

how do i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Spinner.getSelectedItem()` to get the currently selected values from your three spinners, then use those values to determine if you should launch your `Activity`.